# How to align baseline of ordinary text with the baseline in `tabular`?

Tags: tables, spacing

This code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
  \hrule
  TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
  \hrule
  \begin{tabular}[t]{rc}
    TEXT & TEXT \\
    TEXT & TEXT \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

produces two side-by-side minipages that start with a horizontal line. The left minipage contains ordinary text. The right minipage contains a table. The horizontal lines are at the same height. The baselines of the text are not:

[image]

I want that the baseline of the ordinary text (on the left) is the same as the baseline of the text in the first cell of the table (on the right). This would require either moving the text *down*, or moving the text in the table *up*.

What I tried:

- `\renewcommand\arraystretch{0}` eliminates the top padding, but it also eliminates the bottom padding and changes the height of the cells
- Setting `\arraystretch` to `0` and then replacing table rows by

  ```
  TEXT & TEXT \\[0.5ex]
  ```

  seems to eliminate the top padding and to do roughly what I want, but I would prefer to not contaminate every line of the table with non-DRY magic numbers.

What would be the proper way to align the baselines in the text (left) and the table (right)?

Comment: Do you really want the rule touches the text on the left side?

Comment: @Bernard The horizontal lines are merely supposed to show that the minipages are aligned properly. I the end of the day, I don't want to have any horizontal lines at all. All I want is to make the baselines of text on the left be the same as the baseline of the text on the right. The extra whitespace prevents this from happening. My assumption is that the whitespace marked with red arrows is some kind of table cell padding. I want to set it to zero, somehow.

Comment: The simplest solution would be to slightly lower the text on the left side: just add a `\strut` before the text.

Comment: the following mwe works perfectly: `\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.22\linewidth}
TEXT  TEXT 
\end{minipage}\begin{minipage}[t]{0.22\linewidth}
\begin{tabular}[t]{cc}
TEXT & TEXT \\
TEXT & TEXT \\
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}`. it seems that unknown option `H` in `tabular` environment cause (together with `hrule`) troubles ...

Comment: @Bernard Ok, maybe you are right, and I invented an unnecessary XY-problem. I reformulated the question in a way that it becomes answerable with your `\strut`-solution.

Comment: BTW, tabular is not a float, so no H option.  The t/b/c option controls where the baseline is placed: top line, bottom line or center.  Default is center.

Comment: However, the fop line of the minipage is \hrule, so that is what is aligned here.  Every line after that is a matter of matching the spacing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an explicitation of my comment: adding a `strut` in the first line of the left-hand side tex  lowers this line exactly at the same level as the first row of the `tabular`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
  \hrule
  \strut TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT

\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
  \hrule
  \begin{tabular}[H]{rc}
    TEXT & TEXT \\
    TEXT & TEXT \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]